# p5.js Change Image on Click and Issue with blinking character

Tags: javascript, p5.js

The goal is to create a game of bug squishing. There is a count and a timer. The issues are 1) the bugs are blinking, when they should not be, and 2) when each bug is clicked, there is supposed to be an image of the bug squished, which I have saved as image name: sprite_bug7.png. I am unsure how to resolve both issues and have been working all day to figure it out!

```
var bug = [];
var count = 10;
let timer = 30;
var counter = 0;
var score = 0;`enter code here`
var squish;

function preload(){
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        bug[i] = new Crawler("bugs.png", random(610), random(400), 
        random(-1,1));
        squish = loadImage('sprite_bug7.png');
      }
}
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(640,480);
    imageMode(CENTER)
  }

function draw(){
  background(255);
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){   
    bug[i].draw();
  }
  text("Score: " + score, 20, 30);
  text("Time Left: " + timer, 20, 45);
  if ((frameCount % 60 == 0) && (timer > 0)){
    timer--;
  }
  if (timer == 0){
    text("GAME OVER", 300, 250);
    text("You scored: " + score, 300, 265)
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    bug[i].kill(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}

function Crawler(imageName, x, y, moving){
    this.spriteSheet = loadImage(imageName);
    this.frame = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.moving = moving;
    this.facing = moving;

    this.kill = function(x,y){
      if((this.x-30<x && x < this.x+30 && this.y-30<y && y<this.y+30)|| 
        (timer==0)){
        this.moving = 0;
        score = score + 1;
        this.bug = squish;
        }
        if (this.alive == 1){
          this.alive = 0;
        }
    }


    this.draw = function(){
        push();
        translate(this.x,this.y);
        if (this.facing < 0){
            scale(-1.0, 1.0);
         }
        if (this.moving == 0){
          image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
         } 
        else{
            if (this.frame == 0){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 200, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 1){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 300, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 2){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 400, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 3){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 500, 0, 100, 100100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 4){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 600, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 5){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 700, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 6){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 800, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 7){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, this.x, this.y, 100, 100, 800, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (frameCount % 4 == 0){
            this.frame = (this.frame+1)%8;
            this.x = this.x + this.moving *6;
            }
            if(this.x < 30){
                this.moving = +1;
                this.facing = +1;
            }
            if(this.x> width-30){
                this.moving = -1;
                this.facing = -1;
            }
          } 
         pop();
       }
  }
```

Comment: you should create a jsfiddle or something. so we can help more easily. like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/SamyBencherif/5xuxrwpu/
but with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The bugs are blinking because of the coordinates you're using to draw the image in the 'last' frame. You're already using `translate`, so when you use `this.x` and `this.y` in the last frame, the image 'jumps' and produces the blinking effect.

2) The bug isn't displaying the squished image because it isn't actually being drawn at any point. You have the line `this.bug = squish` but never use it inside the `image` method.

I don't have access to your images so I made some assumptions so I could create a snippet:

```js
let timer = 30;
var counter = 0;
var score = 0;`enter code here`
var squish;

const count = 3
let bug = new Array(3)

function preload(){

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        //bug[i] = new Crawler("bugs.png", random(610), random(400), 
        bug[i] = new Crawler("https://picsum.photos/800/100", random(610), random(400), 
        random(-1,1));
        // squish = loadImage('sprite_bug7.png');
        squish = createGraphics(100, 100)
        squish.background('green')
      }
}
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(640,480);
    imageMode(CENTER)
  }

function draw(){
  background(255);
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){   
    bug[i].draw();
  }
  text("Score: " + score, 20, 30);
  text("Time Left: " + timer, 20, 45);
  if ((frameCount % 60 == 0) && (timer > 0)){
    timer--;
  }
  if (timer == 0){
    text("GAME OVER", 300, 250);
    text("You scored: " + score, 300, 265)
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    bug[i].kill(mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}

function Crawler(imageName, x, y, moving){
    this.spriteSheet = loadImage(imageName);
    this.frame = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.moving = moving;
    this.facing = moving;

    this.kill = function(x,y){
      if((this.x-30<x && x < this.x+30 && this.y-30<y && y<this.y+30)|| 
        (timer==0)){
        this.moving = 0;
        score = score + 1;
        // this.bug = squish;
        this.spriteSheet = squish;
        }
        if (this.alive == 1){
          this.alive = 0;
        }
    }


    this.draw = function(){
        push();
        translate(this.x,this.y);
        if (this.facing < 0){
            scale(-1.0, 1.0);
         }
        if (this.moving == 0){
          /* Made some changes to the coordinates */
          image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
         } 
        else{
            if (this.frame == 0){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 1){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 2){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 200, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 3){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 300, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 4){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 400, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 5){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 500, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 6){ 
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 600, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (this.frame == 7){ 
            // image(this.spriteSheet, this.x, this.y, 100, 100, 800, 0, 100, 100);
            image(this.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 100, 100, 700, 0, 100, 100);//size,size,start,start,end,end
            }
            if (frameCount % 4 == 0){
            this.frame = (this.frame+1)%8;
            this.x = this.x + this.moving *6;
            }
            if(this.x < 30){
                this.moving = +1;
                this.facing = +1;
            }
            if(this.x> width-30){
                this.moving = -1;
                this.facing = -1;
            }
          } 
         pop();
       }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```